# How to get sum value of database table rows along with IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that has batch numbers and distance. It has multiple batch numbers and different distance.

MySql Query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS claim_trips.distance as total_distance, actions.batch_no 
FROM `actions` 
JOIN claim_trips ON actions.batch_no=claim_trips.batch_no 
WHERE actions.stage = 1 AND actions.`status` = 0 
ORDER BY `batch_no` ASC
```

and here's the result

[image]

As in the above screenshot there are 2 different batch numbers. How cant I get the total distances under both batch numbers? any thing to do with MySql Query?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what would be a _correct_ result?

Comment: you need sum per batch_no or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just SUM distanses and GROUP BY batch_no:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    SUM(claim_trips.distance) AS total_distance,
    actions.batch_no
FROM
    `actions`
JOIN claim_trips ON actions.batch_no = claim_trips.batch_no
WHERE
    actions.stage = 1
    AND actions.`status` = 0
GROUP BY
    actions.batch_no
ORDER BY
    `batch_no` ASC
```